# Save this batch variable into a txt file

Tags: batch-file, variables, save

I'm trying to save this batch variable into a .txt file. This is my current code:

```
set /p Build=<version.ini
echo %Build%
type %Build%>>"result.txt"
pause
```

It's supposed to get the text on that .ini file and then save that text into a new .txt file but the result is a long list of random characters. The content of that .ini is a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `echo` and not `type`. You can learn why by opening `cmd` and running `type /?` and `echo /?`

So this will work:

```
set /p Build=<version.ini
echo %Build%
echo %Build%>>"result.txt"
pause
```

Additionally, if it is simply your intention to replicate the text to a new file, this would be much shorter:

```
type version.ini>result.txt
```

or to find specific text only and send to new file.

```
type version.ini | findstr /I "Version" >result.txt
```

or by using `copy`

```
copy version.ini result.txt
```

Comment: Why not using `copy` to replicate a file??

Comment: @aschipfl Copy is another way yes, added as well